# Regex to find string followed by character

Tags: regex

I am a newbie in Regular expressions. What would be the regex to find all "DataKeyNames" followed by "," string?  I am trying to find all text where we have "DataKeyNames" followed by "," in various files.

```
DataKeyNames="AppRevObjId, AsmtIdsOnHold"
```

Comment: what do you want to find? AsmtIdsOnHold? or something else?

Comment: Try `DataKeyNames[^,]*,`

Answer (score 1):

i don't know what is you want to find but :
1) if you want 'AppRevObjId' only use this :

```
import re
s = 'AppRevObjId, AsmtIdsOnHold'
re.findall('([^\s]+),' , s)
```

output :

```
['AppRevObjId']
```

2)  if you only want 'AsmtIdsOnHold' :

```
re.findall(',\s([^\s]+)' , s) # or-> re.findall(', ([^\s]+)' , s)
```

3) if you want both :

```
re.findall('([^\s]+), ([^\s]+)' , s) # or-> re.findall('([^\s]+),\s([^\s]+)' , s)
[('AppRevObjId', 'AsmtIdsOnHold')]
```

output:

```
  [('AppRevObjId', 'AsmtIdsOnHold')]
```

so please explain more or report bugs to fix issues and bugs in codes